# Real time chart data from server socket connection?

Tags: json, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I know a website that uses socket.io

I'm wondering what the best socket application template is for connection to a server as a client, then receiving all of the info and charting it in real-time based on what objects within the json the user(me) chooses.

Just a simple line chart, where you specify what objects you wish to be shown from the socket feed.

I've never worked with sockets before, and after googling all day and reading through the tutorials, I want to make sure this is even possible and I'm not searching for something that doesn't exist.

---

Thank you graciously

.

Comment: Almost always when question contains "What is the best tool, approach, library, framework?" it's opinion based and will be closed as off topic. Just search about `socket.io` and find most popular library. Then come back here if you have specific problem with it

Comment: Just to be clear, you say to search google and run whatever seems to be the most popular code?

Comment: edit, i found this guide for d3 charts https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3js-first-steps. im going to read it and try to figure out how to use it to connect to an existing website socket, wish me luck